# Skipping missing element for <img>

Tags: javascript, html

I am using  to show images, by iterating, say through i. But for some of the entry the image may actually be missing. Is there a way to avoid the broken link icon to be shown? (i.e. skip the element if the image cannot be found)

Comment: I think you missed some words

Comment: You may be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792923/determine-image-src-in-onload-and-onerror-event-handlers-in-ie

Comment: Use OnError attribute of the img tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have some code like this:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

to populate a variable with some images.  You can just set the `onerror` method of the image tag (as mentioned in other answers) to handle the missing images however you want.

This will remove `<img>` tags whose images do not load:

```
for (var i in imgs)
{
    imgs[i].onerror = function() {
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

If you wanted to then load `missing_image.jpg` instead of making the tags disappear (be careful with this one because the browser probably won't detect the infinite loop you can get into if `missing_image.jpg` doesn't exist...):

```
for (var i in imgs)
{
    imgs[i].onerror = function() {
        this.src = 'missing_image.jpg`;
    }
}
```

**Sources**:

1. Javascript Image Object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp
2. Html  Tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Answer (score 1):

Sure... you several things you can do:

**Keep the broken Image size**
If you know the size of the supposed image you can force it using css.

```
.img-broken {
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
   display: block;
}
```

**Have an image replacement**
You want to replace the place-holder with something better.

```
<img src="..." onerror="this.src='/img/broken_img_error.jpg';">
```

**Erase the image altogether**
See @Slave answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script>
    function removeElement(elem) {
        var div = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
        div.removeChild(elem);
    }
</script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <img  onerror='removeElement(this);' src="icon.png" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think javascript is the best approach here at all.

If you can't fix or rely on images always actually existing (it happens, I know), the easiest way to prevent the broken image is to place an `.htaccess` file (or the equivalent, depending on your hosting environment) in your images folder.

The great thing about this approach is that there aren't any worries about browser support. This happens on the server, so the user could be using some ancient proprietary AOL 4.0 browser with javascript disabled and this would still work; you don't have to contend with user agent differences or javascript disabled at all.

I use this one for my user images. The image path is in the database, and sometimes for various reasons, the image specified in the database isn't actually in the folder. This is the contents of the `.htaccess` file located in `images/users/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ images/users/default.png [R=301,L]
```

What this does is silently forwards any requests for non-existent files to the file `default.png`, which is my "no photo available" image. Now, if a request for `images/users/this-does-not-exist.png` comes in, the file `default.png` will be served instead. No broken images!

**Documentation**

- `.htaccess` for Apache - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html
- *URL Rewriting in ASP.NET* on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx
- Helicon Ape - shim .htaccess support for IIS - http://www.helicontech.com/ape/

Answer (score -1):

Outside of making AJAX calls to the image locations to verify you get a 200 result and then showing/hiding accordingly, I can't think of a good way.

Why not just fix the broken image links?